# How to change DPI of .NET chart

Tags: c#, charts

I am using the asp.net MVC chart helper to generate charts for inclusion in a PDF document. My problem is that the PDF needs a higher DPI for the chart to look good. I can actually get around this problem by generating a chart that is 4 or 5 times bigger than I need and simply writing it into a smaller container.

But that creates a new problem: my labels' fonts are 4 or 5 times too small. I have tried using one of the built in chart themes as a base and customising the XML, but some styles just don't want to apply. Note the AxisY and AxisX LabelStyle elements:

```
<Chart BackColor="#C9DC87" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BorderColor="181, 64, 1" BorderWidth="2" BorderlineDashStyle="Solid" Palette="BrightPastel">
<Titles>
    <Title _Template_="All" Text="Title" Font="Trebuchet MS, 32pt, style=Bold">
    </Title>
  </Titles>
<Series>
<Series _Template_="All" Font="Trebuchet MS, 32pt, style=Bold">
    </Series>
</Series>
  <ChartAreas>
    <ChartArea _Template_="All" BackColor="Transparent" BackSecondaryColor="White" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid" ShadowColor="Transparent">
      <AxisY LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64">
        <MajorGrid Interval="Auto" LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
        <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 32pt, style=Bold" />
      </AxisY>
      <AxisX LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64">
        <MajorGrid LineColor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
        <LabelStyle Font="Trebuchet MS, 32pt, style=Bold" />
      </AxisX>
      <Area3DStyle Inclination="15" IsRightAngleAxes="False" Perspective="10" Rotation="10" WallWidth="0" />
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
  <Legends>
    <Legend _Template_="All" Alignment="Center" BackColor="Transparent" Docking="Bottom" Font="Trebuchet MS, 32pt, style=Bold" IsTextAutoFit ="False" LegendStyle="Row">
    </Legend>
  </Legends>
  <BorderSkin SkinStyle="Emboss" />
</Chart>
```

and the actual chart:

[image]

The chart's x and y labels are way too small. They're at the default 8.25pt, even though I specify them as 32pt.

SO basically, I either need to know how to increase the DPI so that I don't have to squash down my chart, OR how to get those labels to display bigger than they are.

Comment: Just as an FYI, DPI meants "dots (=pixels) per inch", and is used as a measurement for screens. It's a hardware concept, not a software concept. If anything, *increasing* DPI means *more* pixels per inch, thus even smaller text.

Comment: Yes, the point is that I need a higher DPI image for the chart to look smooth. I get pixelation if I use the correct size chart, rather than squashing it. If I use an oversized chart I get a smoother, better quality image, but the labels are too small. To fix THAT, I need to get the styling to work properly. Or else, I need to know how to increase the DPI/quality of the chart itself so that It will render smoothly without needing to be drawn at 5 times the size.

Comment: You are solving the entirely wrong problem.  DPI is just a reference number, it indicates the resolution of the device that generated the image.  It is only important to ensure that the image is displayed on another device with a different resolution at (roughly) the same physical size.  Important for printers for example, high resolution devices that turn your image into a postage stamp if you display 1:1.  You simply need more pixels to get a better result.  Make the chart bigger.   Usually 6 times bigger to get enough quality for a printout.

Comment: How do I change the label size of my line chart? The chart seems to ignore my Font style.

Comment: Your code looks correct and I really don't know why it doesn't work properly. However, from your post I understand that you would like to display a good quality chart with smoother line, but you don't want to pay -  so I would suggest you to have a look at the [free editions](https://www.nevron.com/products-dot-net-chart-free-control.aspx) of the professional charting components.

Comment: Dundas Charts (which is now MSCharts, which is used by the MVC helper) is actually pretty good. It's just that it seems to have a bug in the line chart output which ignores label font sizes. If I change chart type to e.g. pie chart, the labels' font size property is applied correctly.